# Atribuir item selecionado a Jcombobox

Tags: java, swing, combobox

Estou com um problema onde os valores dos meus jComboBox não estão sendo retornados mas os valores no banco estão corretos.

Tenho um jFrame de Cadastro de veiculo, que quando acionado o botão de pesquisa, chama o metodos `pesquisaVeiculo` e chama um jDialog para pesquisa no banco de dados.  Logo apos selecionar o veiculo desejado, ele fecha e retorna os valores no jFrame de `CadastroDeVeiculo`, mas os jComboBox nao retorna valor algum, fica com o item Default selecionado, já os jTextField volta com os valores que foram selecionados.

jFrame = CadastroDeVeiculos

```
    public class CadastroDeVeiculos extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private Connection conexao;//Cria metodo de conexao

    //Construtor
    public CadastroDeVeiculos(){
        initComponents();
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    } 

    public void pesquisaVeiculo(){
        //Cria as variaveis e seta os valores dos get and set pegados na classe Veiculo
        PesquisaVeiculo pesquisa = new PesquisaVeiculo(this,true);
        pesquisa.setVisible(true);

        //Cria as variaveis
        Long id = pesquisa.getId_veiculo();
        String modelo = pesquisa.getModelo_veiculo();
        String cor = pesquisa.getCor_veiculo();
        int ano = pesquisa.getAno_veiculo();
        String placa = pesquisa.getPlaca_veiculo();
        String estado = pesquisa.getEstado_veiculo();
        String marca = pesquisa.getMarca_veiculo();
        String observacoe = pesquisa.getObservacoes_veiculo();
        Double valorMin = pesquisa.getValor_minimo_veiculo();
        Double valorMed = pesquisa.getValor_medio_veiculo();
        Double valorMax = pesquisa.getValor_maximo_veiculo();
        int quantidade = pesquisa.getQuantidade_veiculo();
        String tipo = pesquisa.getTipo_veiculo();

        //Seta os valores nos campos
        jTextFieldIdVeiculo.setText(String.valueOf(id));
        jTextFieldModelo.setText(modelo);
        jTextFieldCor.setText(cor);
        jTextFieldAno.setText(String.valueOf(ano));
        jFormattedTextFieldPlaca.setText(placa);
        jTextFieldEstado.setText(estado);
        jComboBoxMarca.setSelectedItem(marca);
        jTextFieldObservacoes.setText(observacoe);
        jFormattedTextFieldValorMin.setText(String.format("%.3f",(valorMin)));
        jFormattedTextFieldValorMed.setText(String.format("%.3f", (valorMed)));
        jFormattedTextFieldValorMax.setText(String.format("%.3f", (valorMax)));
        jTextFieldQuantidade.setText(String.valueOf(quantidade));
        jComboBoxTipo.setSelectedItem(tipo);
    }
}
```

jDialog = PesquisaVeiculo

```
    public class PesquisaVeiculo extends javax.swing.JDialog {

    private Long id_veiculo;
    private String modelo_veiculo;
    private String cor_veiculo;
    private int ano_veiculo;
    private String placa_veiculo;
    private String estado_veiculo;
    private String marca_veiculo;
    private String observacoes_veiculo;
    private double valor_minimo_veiculo;
    private double valor_medio_veiculo;
    private double valor_maximo_veiculo;
    private int quantidade_veiculo;
    private String tipo_veiculo;

    //GETTER AND SETTER
    public String getTipo_veiculo() {
        return tipo_veiculo;
    }

    public void setTipo_veiculo(String tipo_veiculo) {    
        this.tipo_veiculo = tipo_veiculo;
    }

    public Long getId_veiculo() {
        return id_veiculo;
    }

    public void setId_veiculo(Long id_veiculo) {
        this.id_veiculo = id_veiculo;
    }

    public String getModelo_veiculo() {
        return modelo_veiculo;
    }

    public void setModelo_veiculo(String modelo_veiculo) {
        this.modelo_veiculo = modelo_veiculo;
    }

    public String getCor_veiculo() {
        return cor_veiculo;
    }

    public void setCor_veiculo(String cor_veiculo) {
        this.cor_veiculo = cor_veiculo;
    }

    public int getAno_veiculo() {
        return ano_veiculo;
    }

    public void setAno_veiculo(int ano_veiculo) {
        this.ano_veiculo = ano_veiculo;
    }

    public String getPlaca_veiculo() {
        return placa_veiculo;
    }

    public void setPlaca_veiculo(String placa_veiculo) {
        this.placa_veiculo = placa_veiculo;
    }

    public String getEstado_veiculo() {
        return estado_veiculo;
    }

    public void setEstado_veiculo(String estado_veiculo) {
        this.estado_veiculo = estado_veiculo;
    }

    public String getMarca_veiculo() {
        return marca_veiculo;
    }

    public void setMarca_veiculo(String marca_veiculo) {
        this.marca_veiculo = marca_veiculo;
    }

    public String getObservacoes_veiculo() {
        return observacoes_veiculo;
    }

    public void setObservacoes_veiculo(String observacao_veiculo) {
        this.observacoes_veiculo = observacao_veiculo;
    }

    public double getValor_minimo_veiculo() {
        return valor_minimo_veiculo;
    }

    public void setValor_minimo_veiculo(double valor_minimo_veiculo) {
        this.valor_minimo_veiculo = valor_minimo_veiculo;
    }

    public double getValor_medio_veiculo() {
        return valor_medio_veiculo;
    }

    public void setValor_medio_veiculo(double valor_medio_veiculo) {
        this.valor_medio_veiculo = valor_medio_veiculo;
    }

    public double getValor_maximo_veiculo() {
        return valor_maximo_veiculo;
    }

    public void setValor_maximo_veiculo(double valor_maximo_veiculo) {
        this.valor_maximo_veiculo = valor_maximo_veiculo;
    }

    public int getQuantidade_veiculo() {
        return quantidade_veiculo;
    }

    public void setQuantidade_veiculo(int quantidade_veiculo) {
        this.quantidade_veiculo = quantidade_veiculo;
    }

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //Metodos para pesquisa


    DefaultTableModel tmVeiculo = new DefaultTableModel(null, new String[]{"Id", "Modelo", "Cor", "Ano", "Placna","Estado" , "Marca",
        "Obeservações","Valor min.","Valor med.","Valor max.", "Quantidade", "Tipo"});//Colunas do JTablePesquisaVeiculo
    List<Veiculo> veiculo;
    ListSelectionModel lsVeiculo;

    //Construtor
    public PesquisaVeiculo(java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal) {
        super(parent, modal);
        initComponents();
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    //Metodo para mostrar pesquisa no JTable
    public void mostraPesquisa(List<Veiculo> veiculo) {
        while(tmVeiculo.getRowCount()>0){
            tmVeiculo.removeRow(0);
        }
        if (veiculo.size() == 0) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Nenhum veiculo cadastrado!");
        } else {
            String[] linhaVeiculo = new String[]{null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null};

            for (int i = 0; i < veiculo.size(); i++) {
                tmVeiculo.addRow(linhaVeiculo);

                tmVeiculo.setValueAt(veiculo.get(i).getId_veiculo(), i, 0);
                tmVeiculo.setValueAt(veiculo.get(i).getModelo_veiculo(), i, 1);
                tmVeiculo.setValueAt(veiculo.get(i).getCor_veiculo(), i, 2);
                tmVeiculo.setValueAt(veiculo.get(i).getAno_veiculo(), i, 3);
                tmVeiculo.setValueAt(veiculo.get(i).getPlaca_veiculo(), i, 4);
                tmVeiculo.setValueAt(veiculo.get(i).getEstado_veiculo(), i, 5);
                tmVeiculo.setValueAt(veiculo.get(i).getMarca_veiculo(), i, 6);
                tmVeiculo.setValueAt(veiculo.get(i).getObservacoes_veiculo(), i, 7);
                tmVeiculo.setValueAt(veiculo.get(i).getValor_minimo_veiculo(), i, 8);
                tmVeiculo.setValueAt(veiculo.get(i).getValor_medio_veiculo(), i, 9);
                tmVeiculo.setValueAt(veiculo.get(i).getValor_maximo_veiculo(), i, 10);
                tmVeiculo.setValueAt(veiculo.get(i).getQuantidade_veiculo(), i, 11);
                tmVeiculo.setValueAt(veiculo.get(i).getTipo_veiculo(), i, 12);                
            }
        }
    }

    //Campo de pesquisa
    public void campoPesquisa() {
        try {
            VeiculoDao dao = new VeiculoDao();
            veiculo = dao.getListaVeiculo("%" + jTextFieldPesquisar.getText() + "%");
            mostraPesquisa(veiculo);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro ao pesquisar! = " + ex);
        }
    }

    //Seta os valores nos get and set da classe Veiculo
    public void setarDados() {
        int linhaselecionada = jTablePesquisarVeiculo.getSelectedRow();

        if (linhaselecionada!=-1) {

                id_veiculo = Long.valueOf(jTablePesquisarVeiculo.getValueAt(linhaselecionada, 0).toString());
                modelo_veiculo = jTablePesquisarVeiculo.getValueAt(linhaselecionada, 1).toString();
                cor_veiculo = jTablePesquisarVeiculo.getValueAt(linhaselecionada, 2).toString();
                ano_veiculo = Integer.valueOf(jTablePesquisarVeiculo.getValueAt(linhaselecionada, 3).toString());
                placa_veiculo = jTablePesquisarVeiculo.getValueAt(linhaselecionada, 4).toString();
                estado_veiculo = jTablePesquisarVeiculo.getValueAt(linhaselecionada, 5).toString();
                marca_veiculo = jTablePesquisarVeiculo.getValueAt(linhaselecionada, 6).toString();
                observacoes_veiculo = jTablePesquisarVeiculo.getValueAt(linhaselecionada, 7).toString();
                valor_minimo_veiculo = Double.valueOf(jTablePesquisarVeiculo.getValueAt(linhaselecionada, 8).toString());
                valor_medio_veiculo = Double.valueOf(jTablePesquisarVeiculo.getValueAt(linhaselecionada, 9).toString());
                valor_maximo_veiculo = Double.valueOf(jTablePesquisarVeiculo.getValueAt(linhaselecionada, 10).toString());
                quantidade_veiculo = Integer.valueOf(jTablePesquisarVeiculo.getValueAt(linhaselecionada, 11).toString());        
                tipo_veiculo = jTablePesquisarVeiculo.getValueAt(linhaselecionada, 12).toString();                

                dispose();

            } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Nenhum veiculo selecionado!");
            }
    }   

}
```

Classe de controle = VeiculoDao

```
    public class VeiculoDao {
    private Connection conexao;//Cria metodo de conexao

    //Contrutor
    public VeiculoDao() throws SQLException{
        this.conexao = ConexaoBD.getConexao();  
    }

    public List<Veiculo> getListaVeiculo(String nome) throws SQLException{
        //Meotodo para pesquisa veiculos
        String sql = "select * from veiculo where modelo_veiculo like ?";

            PreparedStatement stmt = this.conexao.prepareStatement(sql);
            stmt.setString(1, nome);
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
            List<Veiculo> listaVeiculo = new ArrayList<Veiculo>();

            while(rs.next()){
                Veiculo veiculo = new Veiculo();

                veiculo.setId_veiculo(Long.valueOf(rs.getString("id_veiculo")));
                veiculo.setModelo_veiculo(rs.getString("modelo_veiculo"));
                veiculo.setCor_veiculo(rs.getString("cor_veiculo"));
                veiculo.setAno_veiculo(rs.getInt("ano_veiculo"));
                veiculo.setPlaca_veiculo(rs.getString("placa_veiculo"));
                veiculo.setEstado_veiculo(rs.getString("estado_veiculo"));
                veiculo.setMarca_veiculo(rs.getString("marca_veiculo"));
                veiculo.setObservacoes_veiculo(rs.getString("observacoes_veiculo"));
                veiculo.setValor_minimo_veiculo(rs.getDouble("valor_minimo_veiculo"));
                veiculo.setValor_medio_veiculo(rs.getDouble("valor_medio_veiculo"));
                veiculo.setValor_maximo_veiculo(rs.getDouble("valor_maximo_veiculo"));
                veiculo.setQuantidade_veiculo(rs.getInt("quantidade_veiculo"));
                veiculo.setTipo_veiculo(rs.getString("tipo_veiculo"));

                listaVeiculo.add(veiculo);     
            }
                rs.close();
                stmt.close();
                return listaVeiculo;       
    }

}
```

Tenho também a classe de conexão ao banco, e a de getters e setters da tabela veiculo.

Aqui estão as telas dos model dos jCombobox **modelo** e **tipo**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No JFrameCadastroVeiculo assim que a pesquisa e feita os valores retornam, somente o jComboBox que fica default

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando o botao **Detalhes** e acionado fecha a tela e retorna os valores para o jFrame.

jDialog de pesquisa, com os valores inseridos na hora do cadastro exibidos, ate os do jComboBox.:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como resolver isso?

Comment: Onde você define o model do combobox? Tem muito codigo ai desnecessário pro problema da pergunta.

Comment: Diego F, o model do combo box eu defini pela interface gráfica do netbeans, no menu de propriedades do jComboBox, já criei um também na mão e defini os valores e me retorna o mesmo problema.

Comment: Se o objeto passado para o jcombobox não tiver um relativo identico no model, não vai selecionar nenhum mesmo. Cheque se por acaso os itens do model tem algum campo não preenchido, ou se o item retornado está com algum campo diferente.

Comment: Entao Diego F já conferi os itens do model, ate coloquei eles somente com letras minusculas, mas não adiantou, fiz um teste colocando uma JTTabela no meu frame de cadastro de veículos, e ele retornou os valores no jComboBox certinho. Me ocorre este problema somente se eu usar o JDialog para retornar os valores para o Frame.

Comment: Você chegou a ver se há mesmo um retorno válida em `marca` e `tipo`? Pelos códigos apresentados, nem dá pra testar o problema, tente adicionar um [mcve] para que seja possivel simular o problema.

Comment: posta o codigo de preenchimento do combobox. Mas já adianto que você deve passar o objeto inteiro e não apenas o atributo nome de Marca e Tipo

Comment: Sim, como eu disse se a JTTabela estive no mesmo Frame que quero retornar os valores do banco, o jComboBox me retorna os valores de _marca_ e _tipo_  selecionado. Como seria este tipo de exemplo que poderia postar para ajudar a entender melhor o problema? Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Por que a jdialog possui get e sets? Isso é uma falha de design, Se sua pesquisa retorna um Veiculo, crie um objeto do tipo veiculo, preencha-o com os dados da pesquisa, e retorne um veiculo para o frame.

Comment: Usei os get e sets, pois não tinha conseguido trazer os dados de outra maneira, sou bem leigo ainda em desenvolvimento java, irei fazer o teste de criar o objeto do tipo veiculo, muito obrigado mesmo pela ajuda.

Comment: Adicione como você está preenchendo o dois jcombobox.

Comment: Diego F, Krismorte estive colocando print das telas para melhor entendimento, espero que ajude a entender melhor o meu problema.

Comment: michel, infelizmente na rede onde estou, não consigo visualizar as imagens.

Comment: Tudo bem Diego F, quando tiver um tempo de uma olhada porfavor

Comment: Michel, tente depurar o código, colocando breakpoints no retorno de `tipo` e depois em `marca`, cheque o que está de fato sendo retornado. Lembre-se: `fiat` é diferente de `Fiat` ou  `fiat ` (com espaço no final).

Comment: Diego F consegui consertar, depurei o código e percebi que por declarado uma String *tipo* de tamanho 15 preenchia com espaços em branco o restante da string que tinha sido passada no jComboBox, entao preenchi o model do jComboBox com a string desejada e completei com espaços em branco ate o tamanho definido no banco . E me retornou o valor! Muito obrigado, posta a resposta ae para min marcar como como soluçao.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depurei o código e percebi que por ter declarado uma String **tipo** de tamanho 15 no banco de dados preenchia com espaços em branco o restante da string que tinha sido passada no jComboBox, entao preenchi o model do jComboBox com a string desejada e completei com espaços em branco ate o tamanho definido no banco . E me retornou o valor!

Comment: Ta usando campo `char` no seu banco? Normalmente campos varchars, mesmo com tamanho predefinidos, só usam o necessário pela string armanezada.

Comment: Diego F estou usando o _PostgreSQL_ e minha variável chamada **tipo** esta definida no banco como `character tipo (15)`, qual tipo seria indicado para nao auto completar com espaços em branco?  Obrigado pela ajuda!